# Watchkit: Best way to display a lot of data

Tags: objective-c, swift, watchkit

I am currently learning to develop a watch kit App and I need to display a lot of text. I am using the watch kit label, but it won't show all the text data. It gets cut off. Is there a watch kit object that can display a lot of text and perhaps allow you to scroll through it? I haven't seen this question on stackoverflow so perhaps this question can help others as well.

Comment: I'm sure its possible, however, I don't think anyone is going to want to read a novel on their watch, they'll probably run out of battery before that anyway.

Comment: Why watchkit? Use standard controls. `UITextView`. Just set it to `editable = NO`

Answer (score 1):

Set the number of lines for your `WKInterfaceLabel` to zero.  That will allow the label to grow to the size of the content.  Also, be sure that the size for the height is set to "Size to Fit Content" in your storyboard.